# Block process access to tasklist?

Tags: windows-7, process, administration

The program I use for unlocking my system with a fingerprint/key combination constantly asks if I want to setup a new shortcut for each program I open, this is causing temporary stutters and it keeps detecting all sorts of services as well. I want to stop it from accessing the task list so it basically cannot see what is running on the system thus not detecting when a new program is opened. How would go about doing this?

Comment: Before trying to figure that out, have you check the settings of that program? It's likely that you can disable such a function.

Comment: I have tried to, even checked it's actual config file and so on, there is no way to disable this otherwise, not even through the registry. I need some sort of program access control so it can no longer "see" what's running on the system

Comment: You probably won't be able to restrict API access in that way. What software are you actually using?

Comment: It's an old LogiLink driver package for the fingerprint reader which is bundled it seems with a bit of bloatware for a service they once offered. Can only uninstall the whole package which makes the reader unusable and it's the only driver that thing has :/